# fullPage.js + GSAP Tweenmax Animation

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, gsap

How can I achieve this kind of [website](https://sharp.vn/vn/cong-nghe-long-giat-khong-lo/#), by utilize fullPage.js integrated with GSAP plugins? Tried few times and I'm not very very clear with jQuery code.

The sequence will be:

-Animation start on page load

-When scroll down, animation reverse will trigger first until finish, then follow by jump to next section.

-Animation start on second section page load

--When scroll up on the second section, animation reverse will trigger first until finish, then follow by jump to previous section.

--When scroll down on the second section, animation reverse will trigger first until finish, then follow by jump to next section.

Appreciate your kind advice for this matter.

The unhappy [reproduction demo](https://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1642/).

```
var head = $("#one h1"),
    head2 = $("#two h1");

tl = new TimelineLite();

$("#reverse").click(function(){tl.reverse();});

$("#restart").click(function(){tl.restart();});

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['darkgrey', 'grey', 'lightgrey'],
    scrollingSpeed: 1000,
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {

    var loadedSection = $(this);

    if (index == 1) {
        $(head2).hide();
        tl.staggerFrom(head, 0.2, {scale: 0,autoAlpha: 0}, 0.5)
    }

    if (index == 2) {
        tl.staggerFrom(head2, 0.2, {scale: 0,autoAlpha: 0}, 0.5)
    }

    },
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {

    var leavingSection = $(this);

    if (index == 1 && direction == 'down') {
      //tl.reverse(head, 0.2, {scale: 0,autoAlpha: 0}, 0.5);
      $(head2).show();
    } else if (index == 2 && direction == 'up') {
      $(head2).hide();
      //tl.restart(head, 0.2, {scale: 0,autoAlpha: 0}, 0.5);
    }

  }
});
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 2):

If your issue is animating elements on scroll, I would encourage you to have empty sections with absolute or fixed elements that you can show or hide as you wish by using a fullPage.js callback such as `afterLoad`.

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1654/)

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow'],
    scrollOverflow:true,

    //events
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        $('.element').removeClass('active');
        $('.element' + index).removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');
    },
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        $('.element').addClass('hidden');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.element').addClass('hidden');
        },700);

    },

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Alvaro. I'll try with your demo content.